# how to show Widget only in contact Page in blogger?

Tags: blogger

i tried many conditions but it's not working!

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl + "p/contact-us.html"'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;p/contact-us.html&quot;'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + "p/contact-us.html"'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + &quot;p/contact-us.html&quot;'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == data:blog.homepageUrl + "p/contact-us.html"'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;p/contact-us.html&quot;'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just used page name conditional instead!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22415540)

Comment: it is just a temporary solution!

Answer (score 1):

Use `data:blog.pageId` for testing whether a particular page is being accessed

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageId == "PAGE_ID"'>
...
</b:if
```

The **Page_ID** can be found in the address bar when you are editing a page

[image]

Comment: yes this 'cond' works fine, what can i do now? 
i need to use a global 'cond' like 'data:blog.url' to use it in any blog

Comment: The `data:blog.pageId` condition is available in the global namespace and can be used anywhere in the template code. Is this in any case about the unique value of the **Page_ID** for different blogs?